# use textfield delegate to respond to immediate change in textfield

Tags: swift, core-data, uitextfield, fetch, uitextfielddelegate

My swift code right now uese textfield delegate to change what is display in a label. The problem is the label only changes when the user enters a number and then deletes it. As you can see in the gif below. All I want to do is whent he user enters 1 is for kim kardashian appears on the label. Right now it does it but I have to ener 1 then delete it from the textfield and only then kim kardashian appears on the label.

[image]

```
  import UIKit
  import CoreData


 class ViewController: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate {
@IBOutlet var labelName : UILabel!
@IBOutlet var enterT : UITextField!

lazy var context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    openDatabse()


    enterT.delegate = self

}


func joke(at index : Int) {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Users>(entityName: "Users")
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "idx == %d", Int32(index))
    do {
        if let user = try context.fetch(fetchRequest).first {
            labelName.text = user.username
        }
    } catch {
        print("Could not fetch \(error) ")
    }
}
func openDatabse()
{
    let names = ["kim kardashian", "jessica biel", "Hailey Rienhart"]
    for i in 0..<names.count {
        let newUser = Users(context: context)
        newUser.username = names[i]
        newUser.idx = Int32(i + 1)
    }
    print("Storing Data..")
    do {
        try context.save()
    } catch {
        print("Storing data Failed", error)
    }
}


func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    // return NO to not change text
    print("While entering the characters this method gets called")
    guard let index = Int(textField.text!) else {
         // display an alert about invalid text
         return true
     }
     joke(at: index )


    return true
}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`textField.text` gives the text before making any changes to the `textField`=, i.e. the previously entered `text`. You need to add the `replacementString` to it as well. It is the **new `text`** that is being entered in the `textField`.

So, the `UITextFieldDelegate` method `textField(_: shouldChangeCharactersIn: replacementString)` should look like,

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    // return NO to not change text
    print("While entering the characters this method gets called")
    guard let text = (textField.text as? NSString)?.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string), let index = Int(text) else { //here....
        // display an alert about invalid text
        return true
    }
    joke(at: index )
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this,

```
textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
```

and

```
func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {

}
```

Comment: what do I put in textfieldidchange?

Comment: `shouldChangeCharactersIn` this method's content and check

Comment: @YaoSmith remove `shouldChangeCharactersIn` and copy all its code to `textFieldDidChange`

Answer (score 0):

If you use the function `touchesBegan()` and make the text field `.resignFirstResponder`, you can also add an update function in there.